# Set pager number in FancyCoverFlow android

Tags: android

I am using [FancyCoverFlow](https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow) to make a fancy pager. But I want to add arrows on left and right so that I can move left to right in the FancyCoverFlow. For this, I want to set a page number in the FancyCoverFlow(like we do in ViewPager by setCurrentItem() function). How to acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution, you could achieve this function by a handler with the main looper posting a Runnable in which run(), the below code segment added:

```
***int currentIndex = fancyCoverFlow.getSelectedItemPosition();
currentIndex = (++currentIndex) % banners.size();
fancyCoverFlow.setSelection(currentIndex);***
```